# 400 Bad Request: Apache2 considering request done after HTTP header

Tags: c#, wcf, apache2

I have a problem with a WPF app that is run from Windows machines and use a webservice located on an Apache server. The Windows-computers are members of an AD domain, and the Apache webservice requires (AD) authentication.

The webservice is accessed by WCF. As expected it first attempts to fetch the URL (webservice), gets a 401 Unauthorized then tries again with auth (Windows auth or NTLM auth). With auth it succeeds and everything is fine.

The HTTP connection is Keep-Alive, and 100 expect continue is enabled (but same result without). The header is plain vanilla, and contains Content-Length (i.e. 50kb) as expected.

The problem is that in some cases Apache2 will read *only the header* portion and then return the 401 response. The client, unaware that Apache decided to end it all, continues sending the content (xml). Since this is a keep-alive Apache2 is at this point expecting next request, but instead receives body from first request (XML) and responds with "Bad Request". When WCF sees this response it stops and doesn't resend request with auth header. The Apache log file confirms this as it logs the XML as a bad request where it normally logs the GET, and Wireshark on the client confirms this as I see two HTTP responses from Apache within the one request from the client.

Since the client has added "Content-Length: 54102" in the middle of the header I'd say this is the server that is buggy (note this all happens before any custom code in Apache is executed). The server must expect the content to follow as specified, every HTTP client in the world can't take a (max latency) break waiting for the server to maybe send a header response to the header.

So the way I see it this problem have two solutins:

1. Fix Apache.
2. Make WCF authenticate on first request.

#1 is a server issue better suited for serverfault.
#2 can be done in C# code, but from my Google-research it seems people are able to do this with basic auth (when you can ask the user for user/pass). I however need it as Windows/NTLM auth.

So, my question: How can I have WCF Windows/NTLM authenticate on first request?
Any other thoughts/info around this problem is also welcome.

Comment: The problem description is really thorough, however it seems to ignore the 2 most important questions about itself. 1) "in some cases Apache2 will read only the header portion and then return the 401" Why is that? If that could be answered, probably the problem didn't exist but your description seems not to look for an answer here. 2) "The client, unaware that Apache decided to end it all" How can the client be unaware that the server stopped serving the request after receiving a 401?

Comment: Thanks. I think for both points it is related to how 100 Expect Continue works. (Was hoping maybe someone would provide some clarification around that, and most likely correct me in my statement that the server is buggy.) It seems that either the server breaks HTTP protocol or WCF does (or both do).

Comment: I highly doubt that Apache HTTPd is breaking the HTTP protocol on something that simple and it didn't get noticed. Could you post the HTTP trace?

Comment: @RemiGacogne seems you are correct in that. I've been looking at the .Net source code for System.NetServicePointManager and there are a couple of things. First off .Net will not consider the server to support "100 Continue" if the response is not "100 Continue", meaning a "401 auth needed" will cause the behaviour we are seeing. Secondly it seems a private copy of the static bool `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` is created as the object is created, so setting this just before a request won't work.

Comment: As a sidenote that may (not) be useful to others, WCF seems to have special handling for different IIS versions - but not other servers. Decompile System.dll, find ServicePointManager and search for `IISVersion`. Lots of code related to it after `server.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains("microsoft-iis")` (first parsing version string, then acting upon it).